# Guardado múltiple SQFlite

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

Verán necesito guardar los datos de una lista de items en el SQFlite, lo estoy haciendo con este procedimiento

```
void cargarusuarios() {
      res.forEach((cliente) {
        usuario.usuario = cliente[0].toString();
        usuario.telefono = cliente[1].toString();
        usuario.fechaexpira = cliente[2].toString();
        usuario.email = cliente[3].toString();
        usuario.plan = cliente[4].toString();
        usuario.conexiones = cliente[5].toString();
        DBProvider.db.nuevoUsuario(usuario);
      });
  }
```

El problema es, el procedimiento de guardado se ejecuta correctamente según el numero de clientes pero en todas se guarda solo la información correspondiente al ultimo de ellos.

Pensaría que en cada uno de los pasos guardaría la información de esa iteración y en las siguientes actuaría de la misma manera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que `nuevoUsuario` es asíncrono, intenta usando `Future.forEach` para que espere a que termine cada petición.

```
Future<void> cargarusuarios() async {
 await Future.forEach(res, (cliente) async {
        //aquí lo mejor sería que crees un nuevo objeto usuario en vez de reusarlo
        usuario.usuario = cliente[0].toString();
        usuario.telefono = cliente[1].toString();
        usuario.fechaexpira = cliente[2].toString();
        usuario.email = cliente[3].toString();
        usuario.plan = cliente[4].toString();
        usuario.conexiones = cliente[5].toString();
        await DBProvider.db.nuevoUsuario(usuario);
  });
}
```